# Converting files in base64

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, base64

I have a function in java script that runs through the files.

I have selected by means of an input type:

file multiple, this function lists the files and for each file they add a link "See detail" which in turn when clicking sends to an onchange.

That link I create it when going through the selected files.

The problem is that in this function I need to obtain the balor in BASE64 per file, I only do that when I debug the script from the browser.

If I get Base64 per file but when I do not debugeo it leaves my variable indefinite.

I leave my code.

```
function handleFileSelect(e) {
            console.dir(e);
            if (!e.target.files) return;
            selDiv.innerHTML = "";
            var files = e.target.files;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

                var base64;
                var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("files").files[i]
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = function (fileLoadedEvent) {
                    base64 = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
                    console.log(base64);
                };
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);


                var f = files[i];
                var TmpPath = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[i]);
                var name = f.name;
                var extencion = f.name.split('.')[1];

                selDiv.innerHTML += f.name + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='#' onclick=verdetalle(" + i + ",'" + extencion + "','" + name + "','" + base64 + "','" + TmpPath + "')>Ver Detalle</a>" + "<br/>";
            }
        }
```

this seccion the code is my problem, why?

```
                var base64;
                var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("files").files[i]
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = function (fileLoadedEvent) {
                    base64 = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
                    console.log(base64);
                };
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
```

Comment: base64 is not bit by bit operation. therefore compressing file is not recommended.

Comment: so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. FileReader works asynchronously. `base64` is `undefined` during for-loop.
2. You are using function-scope variables. It overwrites variables.

`async function` type:

```js
document.querySelector( "input" ).addEventListener( "change", handleFileAsync );

async function handleFileAsync ( event ) {
  async function readFile( file ) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let result = new Promise( resolve => reader.addEventListener( "load", resolve ) );
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer( file );
    
    return { name: `name: ${file.name}`, ArrayBuffer: ( await result ).srcElement.result }
  }
  let files = event.srcElement.files;
  let promises = [];
  for ( const file of files ) {
    promises.push( readFile( file ) );
  }
  console.log( await Promise.all( promises ) );
}
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple>
```

Equivalent normal function as above:

```js
document.querySelector( "input" ).addEventListener( "change", handleFile );

function handleFile ( event ) {
  let files = event.srcElement.files;
  let promises = [];
  for ( const file of files ) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    promises.push(
      new Promise( resolve => reader.addEventListener( "load", resolve ) )
      .then( result => ( { name: `name: ${file.name}`, ArrayBuffer: result.srcElement.result } ) )
    );
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer( file );
  }
  Promise.all( promises ).then( list => console.log( list ) );
}
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple>
```

For using console, heading code uese `.readAsArrayBuffer` instead of `.readAsDataURL`.